# Postgis installation on Ubuntu 15.10 server gives dependencies error

Tags: server, 15.10, postgresql

I am trying to install Postgis on Ubuntu server 15.10 using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2
```

but I am getting following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2 : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installable
```

Answer (score 0):

The package name for libgdal1h has been changed to **libgdal1i** after 15.04 Vivid.

Also, it looks like this postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2 package is [available only in 16.04 Xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2&searchon=names).

You should try to install **postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1** for 15.10 Wily instead, just run `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1`, check the [launchpad postgis package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgis) for more detail.